# error in running exe

Tags: c, release, exe, codeblocks

I am trying to make an exe version of my code, this code that has 3 arguments running perfectly in "debugging" and "release" mode on code blocks, the problem is that when I am trying to run the ".exe" file in cmd it tells me that there's an error in the arguments. Note that I changed the arguments in "set programs' arguments" menu for both "debugging" and "release"modes, but also that didn't make any sense!

please any advice?

Comment: Give us command that you are using to run this program, and part of the program which is processing cmd line arguments (argc and argv).

Comment: I think the question is vague and I don't really see the question being directed at the Code::Blocks IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code blocks passes the arguments to the executable on the command line.  In cmd, you must do that manually since the settings in code blocks no longer apply.

Comment: thank you, I didn't see that I am so stupid ever like this moment!